# Find byte array inside another byte array and extract x amount of bytes

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

Any idea how I can find a byte array inside a byte array?

Example

```
byte[] array1 = { 101, 21, 92, 1, 92, 0, 132, 0, 22 }
byte[] search = { 21, 92 }
```

so use array search and find it inside array1 then extract x amount of bytes
after the search array up until specific bytes are reached such as,

```
0, 132, 0, 22
```

Extraction for example would be in this scenario

```
1, 92
```

from `array1`

Comment: How could the question and the given answer possibly be correct

Comment: @TheGeneral well his answer was right to some extent, it was capable of getting the bytes past the specified sequence, from there I made my own adjustments to prevent extract all bytes past said bytes. I felt he deserved the answer overall.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```cs
byte[] array1 = { 101, 21, 92, 1, 92, 0, 132, 21, 0, 22 };
byte[] search = { 21, 92 };
var data = search.Where(a => array1.Contains(a)).ToList();
foreach (var item in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```